# How to download a folder to my local PC from Google Cloud console

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, console

I have a folder I want to download from Google Cloud Console using the Linux Ubuntu command terminal. I have logged in to my SSH console and so far I can only list the contents of my files as follows.

```
cd /var/www/html/staging
```

Now I want to download all the files from that staging folder.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, if I'm missing the point. Anyway, I came here seeking a way to download files from Google Cloud Console. I didn't have the ability to create an additional bucket as the author above suggested. But I accidently noticed that there is a button for exactly what I needed.

Seek keebab-style menu button. In the appearing dropdown you should find Download button.

[image: Menu screenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean cloud shell, then I typically use the gcp storage tool suite.

In summary, I transfer from cloud shell to gcp storage, then from storage to my workstation.

1. First, have the Google cloud ask installed on your system.
2. Make a bucket to transfer it into with `gsutil mb gs://MySweetBucket`
3. From within cloud shell, Move the file I to the bucket. `gsutil cp /path/to/file gs://MySweetBucket/`
4. On your local system pull the file down. `gsutil cp gs://MySweetBucket/filename`

Done!